# Get vscode side bar back to its default settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

After moving explorer section from the side bar and put it down in the panel (problems, output, terminal etc.) I can't access it via `ctrl + shift + e` key shortcut. Also when I put it back and press the three dots `Folders` is ticked but disabled. This a screenshot:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Comment: Oh wow. I guess "Folders" is disabled to uncheck by default, in my VS Code it is similar (marked and disabled). Do you mean something other then this under "default settnings"?

Comment: OK that's reasonable. The main problem is that I can't access it through a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Well.

> Also when I put it back and press the three dots Folders is ticked but
> disabled

Default VS Code behavior, don't see problem here.

0. Click on code input field and try again.
1. Close VS Code and open again.
2. If #1 doesn't help, open Key Bindings (`Ctrl+K Ctrl+S`) and search `ctrl shift e` or `show explorer`. If shortcut is not there, make it reset to default. If it's there, it looks like a VS Code bug.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I found it. If you right-click on the `Folders` icon it has an option "Reset Location". So it gets back to its usual "Explorer" location with all shortcuts working etc.
This happened because of February's news, update post where they mentioned about a new moveable explorer feature and I experimented to see how it works...